# Export Comments only from PDF using VB.Net

Tags: excel, vb.net, pdf

I'm attempting to programmatically retrieve only the comments from a pdf file. I'm in a VB.NET environment where I just export comments and put them to worksheets, just like I would manually export the pdf comments into ".fdf" from a pdf reader. For coding, I use Visual Studio.
I've spent a lot of time looking for any leads on this, but so far I've come up empty.
Any suggestions or discussions are appreciated.

Comment: You probably need to focus your question a bit as it's pretty broad.  Number of steps in this any of which could be the problem.  Many 3rd party pdf tools that will simplify opening and reading the pdf content, or possibly you might need to use OCR depending on the nature of these comments? Same with Excel, many 3rd party libraries simplify Excel documents or Office Interops.

Comment: @Husey, Thanks for the suggestions. Actually, I am looking for any third-party pdf tool library that is FREE and can solve my problem.

Comment: Might be worth you asking on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com or check nugets and/or VS marketplace

Answer (score 0):

`cpdf -list-annotations-json in.pdf` should output all the annotations in JSON format. You will have to dig slightly to extract just the text, but it's all there. Regrettably it's not FDF format (functionality to come) but it might serve your needs.